# A help system for a PHP web app

Tags: php

As our new web app gets more complicated, so the need for help docs increases. I am not talking about documenting code, I am literally talking about application help. So myapp/help, or for example, enabling context help from a particular point in the app with a link such as myapp/help/users/create/ etc.

Are there apps out there for doing this? For example, Wufoo use wordpress for http://wufoo.com/docs/ which I like (and understand wp, so its a nice solution), and Xero have a lovely ASPX http://help.xero.com/ interface. But I'm thinking there might be more dedicated implementations for what I'm looking for. We're on a linux, apache, postgresql, php stack, but a mysql supported installation is not the end of the world.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this? It's a bit of a minefield when googling php + help + system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try a more 'non-blogging' content management system for this, because all you really need is to have a straight up help site.

One option it to use a wiki. There are many options out there for wikis (One is MediaWiki), and you have the added benefit of community editing.

Other than that, try Drupal, Joomla, or one of the many other standard CMS's. They allow you to provide content with a very straight-forward interface.(It isn't weighed down by trying to be a wiki or a blog)

Comment: I'm a strong supporter of wikis, they're especially great in situations where you have multiple people that need to edit the info.  I also suggest you keep an open mind and let the general public be allowed to edit this information too, you'll be surprised what a couple motivated customers will accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not roll your own? All you would need is a basic database table containing topics and the help content, and a script to allow users to query this table.

Other than that, if you don't mind the initial set-up work, try rolling a help/reference system out in a Wiki, such as MediaWiki. However, this will involve a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

I use DokuWiki for this - lots of plugins, easy to use, good access controls and version control.

C.